# Form Submit Controller Redirectes to Different View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, redirect, html.beginform

I'm using a MVC form to send some data to Account/Manage Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account",  FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

I'm using the same form in another view too, but the way it is set up now, after each submit, it redirects the user to Account/Manage view page.

Is there a way that I can send the form to Account/Manage controller and redirects the user to another view page? Is this something that I can achieve with RouteValue?

I can't do that in Account/Manage Controller since only when on specific view I want user to be redirected to a view other than Account/Manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did as a workaround was to add a hidden element to the form.

```
@Html.Hidden("Hidden", "UsersPage" ) //type="hidden", value="UsersPage"
```

I checked the value of the hidden element (text) in controller and based on that redirected to different views.